# Why does ASP.Net fail to serve pages while doing an SVN Update? Does VSS behave better?

Tags: asp.net, svn, tortoisesvn

if I update an ASP.Net application or even just a virtual directory containing XML files, ASP.Net will not serve any pages for that application until the update is done. Why?

Can it be prevented with some .Net code? Does VSS behave better?

My clients can't use the website while I update simple XML files. Very inefficient.

Carl

Comment: are you doing an SVN Export or Checkout to the target folder?

Comment: Are the xml files in the bin folder?

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN. I'm simply doing a Tortoise update. The XML files are not in the bin folder.

Comment: Maybe tortoise locks the folder?

Answer (score 2):

VSS is **never** better, as it simply does not work.
You are always in danger of losing *all* your codehistory. Not sure if your clients will appreciate this..

Here some references:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html
http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html
http://weblogs.asp.net/jdennany/archive/2005/04/05/397274.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen.  jrummell has probably hit the nail on the head...

There is no explicit interaction between the SVN client and IIS, unless you are using some crazy custom SVN client that stops the web service before it updates.  Therefore it shouldn't affect the behavior of IIS.  Probably what is happening is that you are updating files which are triggering an app restart.